# Why is the ideal gas law said to be classical when it assumes quantized energy states?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, ideal-gas

We are told in my thermodynamics class that the ideal gas law is a classical law that follows from classical mechanics. However, when we derived it as follows, we computed the partition function $Z_1$ for one particle, by summing over quantized energy states $Z_1=\sum_{n_x, n_y, n_z} e^{-\frac{\hbar^2 \pi^2}{2 m L^2 \tau}\left(n_x^2+n_y^2+n_y^2\right)}$ where $n_i$ are translational degrees of freedom. This assumes quantum mechanics! Then the overall partition function was $Z = \frac{1}{N!}Z_1^N$ since they are non-interacting, and then we computed the free energy $F = -\tau \ln Z$, which gave us the ideal gas law for pressure using $p = -(\frac{dF}{dV})_\tau$.

The only assumptions I understand are made are that 1) gas particles are
non-interacting point masses with 2) quantized energy that 3) depends only on translational motion. Due to the final assumption, and in particular, the presence of $\hbar$ in the derivation, this doesn't seem to be a "classical law" to me?

Comment: The fact that one can derive the ideal gas law from appropriate quantum and statistical mechanics methods does not mean that the ideal gas law is not classical. It just means that both approaches end up in the same place, which is a good thing.

Comment: I guess my main question is why would $\hbar$ show up in something deduced by classical means?

Comment: PV=nRT has no h-bar in it. Classically it was a (reasonably valid) observation. Further, any linkage of statistical mechanics (quantum or otherwise) to thermodynamics is based on various assumptions.

Comment: The literal ideal gas equation does not, but the Sackur-Tetrode equation for entropy of a monatomic ideal gas does. Why?

Comment: The Sackur-Tetrode equation is based on quantum statistics counting of possible phases, with one cell having volume $h^{3N}$. It is a theoretical result of quantum statistical physics, not a measurable property of ideal gas. In classical theory, we count states differently and different entropy comes out, independent of $h$. Difference between the two predictions can possibly show at very low temperatures, but gases tend to be not ideal so hard to check experimentally.

Comment: Possibly of interest: ["Why isn't the entropy of gas infinite if there are infinite microstates available?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/371656/146039), ["Why is entropy defined as a discrete sum over all microstates in classical case?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/233605/146039), ["Why don't all gasses have infinite entropy?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/439522/146039), ["Infinite number of microstates?"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/516639/146039).

Answer (score 0):

It's been known for years that h shows up in purely classical (i.e., non-quantum mechanical and/or non-relativistic) derivations- which is a very cool thing. For example, there's a derivation of the strength of the Casimir effect (due to a guy named Boyer, I'll cite the full reference if I can find it in my archives) out of which h emerges when you do the algebra. Boyer explains that it appears there as a conversion factor between different ways of expressing energy.

Regarding why the computation of the partition function gets an h in it, it *might* be (that is, I'm waving my hands here) that the quantized energy states represent the statistical binning process i.e,  the bins are discretized even though the energies of the particles grouped into any given bin are not.

Comment: https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.182.1374 and 10.1088/0305-4470/36/26/313

Comment: Boyer's derivations usually *assume* presence of zero point radiation with density that is function of frequency and $\hbar$, just like it comes out of quantum theory of EM radiation where canonical quantization leads to each oscillator having zero point energy $\hbar \omega/2$. So $h$ does not emerge in Boyer's papers, it is put in by hand as a physical assumption, motivated by the QT of radiation.

Comment: @JánLalinský, is this true of his derivation based on the casimir effect?

Comment: @nielsnielsen Not sure which derivation/paper you mean.

Comment: @JánLalinský , it was in an article that ran in Scientific American many years ago.